# Automate Excel with VBScript to process Nagios Logs

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I'm using VBScript to extract a LOG file from Nagios XI. I have automated a script that will use IE.Aplication `navigate`, choose the right parameters (to filter) and export as CSV (Excel usable). That has been done!

Now I want to filter MORE (of what Nagios can't do). I have multiple logs of CPU, and I want to DELETE ALL the rows contain this word. I found lots of scripts in VBA, but the problem in my case that I override the file each use this is the vba script I use (in another Excel). I need to change it to work from "outside" of the application (meaning from the main script)

```
Sub CellColor(rng As Range)
  For Each row In rng.Rows
    For Each cell In row.Cells
      If cell.Value = ActiveCell.Value Then  '--- The Condition of the function
        cell.Style = "Bad"                   '--- Changing the "Style" atribbute
      Else
        cell.Style = "Good"                  '--- Changing the "Style" atribbute
      End If
    Next cell
  Next row
End Sub
```

Can any body advise on how to convert this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel can be automated via VBScript by using the respective COM object:

```
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True

Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\path\to\your.xls")
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

Set rng = ws.Range("B3:E5")

For Each row In rng
  For Each cell In row.Cells
    If cell.Value = xl.ActiveCell.Value
      cell.Style = "Bad"
    Else
      cell.Style = "Good"
    End If
  Next
Next

wb.Save
wb.Close

xl.Quit
```

However, since the `Range` object has a `Cells` property as well, the loops can be simplified to this:

```
For Each row In rng.Cells
  If cell.Value = xl.ActiveCell.Value
    cell.Style = "Bad"
  Else
    cell.Style = "Good"
  End If
Next
```

Note that either way you **must** use `xl.ActiveCell.Value` instead of just `ActiveCell.Value`, because in VBScript there is no implicit use of the `Application` object (`ActiveCell.Value` in VBA is short for `Application.ActiveCell.Value`).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vbscript/info) for more information about the differences between VBScript and VBA.

The range in the code above is just an example. If you want to process the entire used range in a sheet, replace it with

```
Set rng = ws.UsedRange
```

For removing rows if any of the cells contain the word "CPU" you could do something like this:

```
For Each cell In rng.Cells
  If InStr(cell.Value, "CPU") > 0 Then cell.EntireRow.Delete
Next
```

You could also remove the lines from the CSV before opening it in Excel:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

filename = "C:\path\to\your.csv"

Set inFile  = fso.OpenTextFile(filename)
Set outFile = fso.OpenTextFile(filename & ".tmp", 2)

Do Until inFile.AtEndOfTextStream
  line = inFile.ReadLine
  if InStr(line, "CPU") = 0 Then outFile.WriteLine line
Loop

inFile.Close
outFile.Close

fso.DeleteFile filename, True
fso.MoveFile filename & ".tmp", filename
```

A batch file might be a simpler way to achieve this, though:

```
findstr /v "CPU" your.csv >your.csv.tmp
del your.csv
ren your.csv.tmp your.csv
```

Comment: This is GREAT !!! but what do I to delete the entire ROW if a cell contains the CPU word I know it has some thing to do with InSRT but I don't really understand HOW to implant it I found here this example 'If InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Text, "CPU", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then' and 'ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete' AND I don't have a predefined RANGE it can be 10 rows and it can be 110 , so I want it to go through ALL the filled ROWS Thanks !!!

Comment: See updated answer. And please only accept an answer if it actually does solve your problem.